# Subversion/svn Propfind 405 error after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu

I've upgraded the Ubuntu server hosting my Subversion repository and now can't access svn.

```
http://hostname/svn
```

is giving me no response and Subclipse says :

```
Propfind 405 method not allowed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that during the upgrade process I had opted to overwrite **dav_svn.conf** in /etc/apache2/mods-available/ with a new version - effectively de-configuring Subversion in apache.

Fortunately the upgrade process saved a copy of the original as dav_svn.conf.dpkg-old in the same directory, so I was able to use the following to see the differences and restore the configuration:

```
diff dav_svn.conf  dav_svn.conf.dpkg-old
```

To finish, reload the Apache config:

```
sudo service apache2 graceful
```